# Recording room ambience

Tags: post-production, sfx, ambience, background, room-tone

What would be the best way to record room ambience for ambience fx (not room tone for dialogue) with one mic? I'm limited on that side. Should i just transform mono to stereo later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Record one long shot.
- Split it from the half.
- Put one half to the right channel and the other to left channel.
- Export a stereo file.

This way you will get a very wide stereo image that is hard to get from a stereo field recording and your sounds in the front will be clearly distinct from ambience.

Do not just transform to stereo. If you do that, you will not get a stereo sound but only double the file size because right and left channel will contain the same information and playback will again result in a mono output.

Answer (score 4):

Record 2 mono claps/pulses/shots, however you're generating it.

Move the mic from one side of the room to the other for each, keeping each at the same distance from the source.

Match up the initial claps later, save as stereo.

It won't be perfect, but no-one except you will ever know ;-)